# How to make MacVim launch with the -y option by default?

Tags: macvim

Right now I have to go to a terminal and type: "mvim -y &".
I want to be able to launch MacVim with -y option enabled even when clicking on the .app icon or when launching it through the "Open with..." context menu.
I know about the gvimrc and vimrc files under MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim, so I just need someone to tell me what to add in which file.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to add `set insertmode` to either your .vimrc or .gvmirc files.

If you are setting this because it is your personal preference, you might consider adding the line to the .gvim file in your home directory instead. Modifying the configuration of the application it's self would probably affect other users on the machine.

Comment: well, its not the same as "easy mode" since the shortcuts on easymode are the same as in textedit. In insertmode, while i dont have to press 'i' to write, i still cant use Shift+Arrow to select txt and home/end buttons dont work.   i tried   "set easymode" , but it doesnt work.